# Eclipse Kepler with gcc 4.8 underlines c++11 features std::move, std::unique_ptr, with could not resolve

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, c++11

I am able to compile, and use code that uses some c++11 features as the `std::move` and `std::unique_ptr`. However, in the Eclipse CDT the `std::move` and `std::unique_ptr` are underlined with a red dash stating: "Functiom move could not be resolved", "Symbol `std::unique_ptr`" could not be resolved. I inluded the header files `< memory >` and `< utility >`

I also added as compiler flag `-std=c++11` and added to path and symbols `__GNU_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__`,

As I said code works correctly with expected behaviour, but just cannot get rid of these annoying red dashed under my code.

Comment: I would suggest a switch to QtCreator, it's way more simple, effective and concise and it's meant to be a C++ IDE.

Comment: Please copy and paste your *Command to get compiler specs* here. Also, please make sure that you clean your project and you also manually delete all the error messages. Eclipse somehow saves the error messages and doesn't update them properly; it shows them even if you don't get them anymore.

Comment: Got it resolved, I needed to select new C++ project makeFile Project and then select Generate MakeFiles Automatically in C++ Builder settings, next added the -std=c++11 flags. Before I selected C++ Excecutable project and added the flags.